# Showing that $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$ is a $5$-cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=S_n$, the symmetric group of degree $n$, where $n\geq 5$.

> Let $\alpha=(g~h~i~j~k)$ be a $5$-cycle in $G$. If $\beta$ is any element in $G$, show that $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$ is a $5$-cycle.

Here's what I tried to do: Let $\beta\in S_n$ and $\alpha$ be a $5$-cycle, $(g~h~i~j~k)$, for $n\geq 5$. First write $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$ as a product of $2$-cycles. Then, if one of the $2$-cycles of $\beta$ is the inverse of one of the $2$-cycles of $\alpha$, they will cancel out, but the $2$-cycle of $\beta^{-1}$ will not cancel with anything. Likewise, if a $2$-cycle of $\beta$ is not the inverse of anything in $\alpha$, then it will cancel with its inverse in $\beta^{-1}$. Thus, every $2$-cycle in $\beta$ will cancel with a $2$-cycle in $\beta^{-1}$ or in $\alpha$. Then there will be the same number of $2$-cycles that we started with. Simplifying, we will have a $5$-cycle. Thus, $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$ is a $5$-cycle.

Is this right and/or is there an easier way to show that $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$ is a $5$-cycle?

Comment: In your first conclusion already, if the right-most 2 cycle of $\beta$ shares an element with the left-most 2 cycle of $\alpha$, they don't commute, and your conclusion doesn't always hold (you assume commutativity which only holds for disjoint cycles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\beta\in S_n$, and consider $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$. then $(\beta \alpha \beta^{-1})^5 = \beta \alpha^5 \beta^{-1}=\beta (1) \beta^{-1}= (1)$, so that the order of $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ divides $5$.

Since $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ is not the identity, we see it must have order exactly $5$.

But the only elements of order $5$ in $S_n$ of order 5 are products of disjoint 5-cycles.

Now, think about the set of letters fixed by $\alpha$ and you should be able to force $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ to be a single 5-cycle.

EDIT: We can reorder the letters so that WLOG $\alpha = (12345)$. As noted in the comments, we need only show the result for a generating set of $S_n$, so let's use transpositions.

then consider $\beta = (ab)$, and $\beta \alpha\beta^{-1} = \beta (12345)\beta^{-1}$.

Now, let $i\in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. and consider $\beta \alpha\beta^{-1}(i).$

If $\beta^{-1}(i)>5$, then this is $\beta \alpha\beta^{-1}(i)=\beta\beta^{-1}(i) = i$.

If $\beta^{-1}(i)\leq 5$, then there is some $j\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that $j = \beta^{-1}(i) \Rightarrow \beta(j)=i$.

Thus, $\beta \alpha\beta^{-1}(i) = \beta \alpha(j) = \beta(j+1\mod 5)$ (as this is what $\alpha$ does).

Thus $\beta \alpha\beta^{-1}$, as a permutation, fixes $i$ such that $\beta^{-1}(i)>5$,

and sends $i = \beta(1)$ to $\beta(2)$, sends $i=\beta(2)$ to $\beta(3)$ etc.

Thus, $\beta \alpha\beta^{-1} = (\beta(1)\beta(2)\beta(3)\beta(4)\beta(5))$.

The only reason I set $\alpha = (12345)$ was for it to be easier to read...

Comment: $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}=(\beta(g)~\beta(h)~\beta(i)~\beta(j)~\beta(j))$ is a $5$-cycle right? Was this the single $5$-cycle you were referring to?

Comment: correct... the point was simply that knowing that it has order 5 is not sufficient in general. So working through precisely what conjugation as you have done gives the result :)

Comment: How can we force $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$ to be one cycle?

Comment: You only need to show that the result holds for a generating set, so we can assume that $\beta$ is a cycle, since we can then apply the result one cycle at a time.

Comment: How would I *prove* that $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}=(\beta(g)~\beta(h)~\beta(i)~\beta(j)~\beta(j))$ is a $5$-cycle then? Is this easy to do or not really necessary? Or does it simply follow from the observations you made at the beginning of your answer?

Comment: It isn't bad. Try to think through what both perrmutations due to the $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, and see that they do have the same action. If it is still confusing I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much! Really appreciate all of your help.

Comment: no problem! happy to help

Answer (score 1):

In general cycle structure is invariant under conjugation. This is because $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$ sends $\beta(a)$ to $\beta(\alpha(a))$.

This means that if you have:

$$\alpha=({c_1}_1,{c_1}_2\dots {c_1}_{k_1})({c_2}_1,{c_2}_2\dots {c_2}_{k_2})\dots ({c_n}_1,{c_n}_2\dots {c_n}_{k_n})$$

then

$\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}=(\beta({c_1}_1),\beta({c_1}_2)\dots \beta({c_1}_{k_1}))(\beta({c_2}_1),\beta({c_2}_2)\dots \beta({c_2}_{k_2}))\dots (\beta({c_n}_1),\beta({c_n}_2)\dots \beta({c_n}_{k_n}))$

Comment: Hmm, what I gave you is more than you need, although it is good to know that the conjugacy class of a cycle is always all of the other cycles with the same cycle structure.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$(\underbrace{\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}}_{\neq 1})^5 = \beta \alpha \underbrace{\beta^{-1} \beta}_{1} \alpha \underbrace{\beta^{-1} \beta}_{1} \alpha \underbrace{\beta^{-1} \beta}_{1} \alpha \underbrace{\beta^{-1} \beta}_{1} \alpha \beta^{-1} = \beta \underbrace{\alpha^5}_{1} \beta^{-1} = \beta \beta^{-1} = 1$$

Comment: @WSL This is a hint. I am just struggling with my input.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\alpha$ maps:

$g \to h\\h \to i\\i \to j\\j \to k\\k \to g$

and that $\alpha(m) = m$, for $m \in \{1,2,3,\dots,n\} - \{g,h,i,j,k\}$.

Suppose that $\beta$ maps:

$g \to a\\h \to b\\i \to c\\j \to d\\k \to f$

(we shall see that we are unconcerned with other values of $\beta(m)$).

Note that above means that $\beta^{-1}$ maps:

$a \to g\\b \to h\\c \to i\\d \to j\\f \to k$

We can distinguish two cases:

Case $1$: $m \in \{1,2,3,\dots,n\} - \{a,b,c,d,f\}$

In this case, whatever $\beta^{-1}(m)$ may be, since $\beta^{-1}$ is bijective, we know that:

$\beta^{-1}(m) \neq g,h,i,j,k$.

Thus $\alpha\beta^{-1}(m) = \alpha(\beta^{-1}(m)) = \beta^{-1}(m)$.

So, in this case, $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}(m) = \beta(\alpha(\beta^{-1}(m))) = \beta(\beta^{-1}(m)) = m$.

Case $2$: $m \in \{a,b,c,d,f\}$. In this case, we have $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$ maps:

$a\to g \to h \to b\\b \to h \to i \to c\\c \to i \to j \to d\\d \to j \to k \to f\\f \to k \to g \to a$

So we see that $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$ is the $5$-cycle $(a\ b\ c\ d\ f)$.