# Prove that there is no permutation $\gamma$ such that $\gamma (1 2) \gamma^{-1} = (1 2 3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I need to prove that there is no $\gamma$ such that:

$$\gamma (1 2) \gamma^{-1} = (1 2 3)$$

First of all, I'll try to write $\gamma$ in a generic way:

$$\gamma = (a b c) \implies \gamma^{-1} = (cba)$$

Then we have:

$$(a b c) (1 2) (cba) = (1 2 3)$$

but I have no clue how to continue. I though of following the path of $a$, like, $a$ goes to $c$, but then, for the second cycle on the multiplication, I can't know if $c$ is in the cycle, so I'm not sure where does $c$ goes after that.

How to solve such problems?

Comment: Do you know about the sign homomorphism? If $\phi: S_n \to \{0,1\}$ is the sign homomorphism, then $\phi(\gamma (12) \gamma^{-1}) = \phi((12)) = 1$ but $\phi((123)) = 0$.

Comment: It may be helpful to know that $\gamma (a b c) \gamma^{-1} = (a\gamma \, b\gamma \, c\gamma)$. (where I write $a\gamma$ for the element that $\gamma$ maps $a$ to) This result is of course true for any length of cycle under conjugation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\gamma(12)\gamma^{-1}=(\gamma(1)\gamma(2))$, and the decomposition as a product of disjoint cycles is unique up to the order of the factors.

One can also say that $(12)$, as well as all its conjugates  has order $2$, while $(123)$ has order $3$.

*Added: proof of the formula:*

Let's denote $\tau_{12}$ the transposition $(12)$. We'll prove that any $i\neq \gamma (1), \gamma(2)$ is fixed by the permutation $\gamma \circ\tau_{12}.\circ \gamma $.  Indeed, $j=\gamma ^{-1}(i)\neq 1,2$, so that 
$$(\gamma \circ\tau_{12}\circ \gamma^{-1})(i)=(\gamma \circ\tau_{12})(j)=\gamma (j)=i.$$
On another hand, if $i=\gamma (1) $, then
$$(\gamma \circ\tau_{12}\circ \gamma^{-1})(\gamma (1)) =(\gamma \circ\tau_{12})(1)=\gamma (2).$$

Similarly $(\gamma \circ\tau_{12}\circ \gamma^{-1})(\gamma (2)) =(\gamma \circ\tau_{12})(2)=\gamma (1)$.

Comment: how can I know that $\gamma$ isn't a 3-cycle, neyther a 1-cycle? In such cases, order of the product would be $6$ or $2$. Did you consider the $6$ case?

Comment: Also, how do you know that $\gamma(12)\gamma^{-1}=(\gamma(1)\gamma(2))$? Is there a proof somewhere? My teacher asked us to prove it and we couldn't do it in the class. Thank you so much! <3

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Think of $\gamma$ as a function, and see what your composition does to each point; i.e., compute $(\gamma(12)\gamma^{-1})(\gamma(1)) = (\gamma \circ (12) \circ \gamma^{-1})(\gamma(1))$, and then for $\gamma(2)$, and $\gamma(3)$, and so on. Those three points will be quite revealing.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1263520/23285 (this is for a $5$-cycle, but the reasoning is the same for any cycle length).

Comment: @Guerlando OC: $\gamma$ is what it is, and its order has nothing to do with the problem. Please see m updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

For any $\gamma$, $(\gamma(12)\gamma^{-1})^2$ is the identity permutation. But this is not true of $(123)$.