# How to solve conjugation equations in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Given the permutations $(12)(34)$ and $(56)(13)$

find $a$ such that

$$a^{-1}xa = y$$

I just realized that I don't know how to solve this exercise. My book don't even give examples of how to solve 'cycles' equations. It's confusing to me. Multiplying by $a$ and $a^{-1}$ doesn't help at all.

I've already solved an exercise in cycles euqations that kinda looks like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381528/prove-that-there-is-no-permutation-gamma-such-that-gamma-1-2-gamma-1), which does not require solving. In fact, it delas with the order of the left and rigth sides.

In the exercise below, I know that the rigth side must have order $6$, and so does the left side. But I can't show it's impossible to make the left side having order $6$ too.

Show that there isn't $a$ such that $a^{-1}(123)a = (13)(578)$

Comment: Do you know that for a cycle $(x y z)$ we have $a^{-1} (x y z) a = (xa \, ya \, za)$?

Comment: @RJS ok then I have an equality between cycles, how do I manage this?

Comment: In the first case you can note that $a^{-1}(1 2)(3 4)a = a^{-1}(1 2)a a^{-1}(3 4)a = (1a \, 2a)(3a \, 4a)$ Which tells you what values a suitable permutation $a$ would map 1,2,3 or 4 to. (We could for example pick $1a = 1$ and then we'd know $2a = 3$ and we could further pick $3a = 5$ giving $4a = 6$) This gives an easy method for finding all such $a$ explicitly since we only have to pick out certain values and the rest gets determined. For the second case we just notice that $a^{-1}(1 2 3)a = (1a \,  2a \, 3a)$ which is a three cycle and not a transposition and a three cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose a permutation $a$ (others will work, too) such that:

$a(1) = 5, a(2) = 6, a(3) = 1$ and $a(4) = 3$.

It doesn't matter what we choose for $a(5),a(6)$, as long as we don't pick from the set $\{1,3,5,6\}$, since those values are already "taken".

$a(5) = 2$, and $a(6) = 4$ will do.

Thus $a = (1\ 5\ 2\ 6\ 4\ 3)$ is one possibility.

Answer (score 1):

The key fact to note is that two elements of the symmetric group are conjugate if and only if they have the same number of $k$-cycles in their cycle decomposition for all $k$. In particular, every conjugate of a $3$-cycle is a $3$-cycle, which solves your second exercise.

You have shown in a previous question that 
$$a(i_1i_2\cdots i_k)a^{-1}=(a(i_1)a(i_2)\cdots a(i_k))$$
For any $a$,
$$a(12)(34)a^{-1}=(a(12)a^{-1})(a(34)a^{-1})=(a(1)a(2))(a(3)a(4))$$
So you just need to find a permutation $a$ such that $a(1)=5$, $a(2)=6$, $a(3)=1$, and $a(4)=3$. I promise this is not a hard thing to do, try it.

Comment: "every conjugate of a $3$ -cycle is a $3$ -cycle" is this a theorem? Could you point to me where do I find it?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs You don't have to look far. The result quoted in the post proves it. $a(i_1i_2i_3)a^{-1}=(a(i_1)a(i_2)a(i_3))$. No matter what $a$ is, the right hand side is a $3$-cycle...there's your proof.