How to solve for permutation $\nu$ in the form of a conjugate equation $B = \nu^{-1} A \nu$?
Update on 7 July 2024. I asked my question too hastily. Let me try again.
Let alphabet $\mathbb{A} = \mathtt{ \{ A, B, \cdots, Z \} } $. Let $G = \langle \mathbb{A}^{26}, \cdot \rangle$ be a permutation group. Unknown $N$ is an element in $G$. Both $A, B$ are known and they are in the form of 9, 9, 4, 4-cycles. $\rho$ is cyclic permutation.
Given that,
\begin{align}
B &= \nu^{-1} A \nu  \\
\nu &= N \rho N^{-1}  \\
\textrm{where}\\
A &= \texttt{ (AFOQSKUHG)(BETCDNIYZ)(JWLP)(MRXV) } \\
B &= \texttt{ (AOQXEJBTG)(DNYZKHVUW)(CPRF)(ILMS) } \\
\rho & = \texttt{ (ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ)} \\
\nu &\textrm{ is a 26-cycle too}.
\end{align}
Using elements in $B$, if I will rotate the first 9-cycle and the first 4-cycle before aligning them to those in $A$, then one intermediate solution is,
\begin{align}
\nu &=
\begin{pmatrix}
\texttt{AFOQSKUHG BETCDNIYZ JWLP MRXV} \\
\texttt{JBTGAOQXE DNYZKHVUW PRFC ILMS}
\end{pmatrix}  \\
& = \texttt{ (AJPCZWRLFBDKOTYUQGENHXMIVS)} .
\end{align}
For other solutions, I will start with the second 4-cycle.
\begin{pmatrix}
  \texttt{... ... ... MRXV} \\
  \texttt{... ... ... MSIL}
\end{pmatrix}
can't be a solution, because $\texttt{(M)}$ makes that $\nu$ fails to become a 26-cycle.
\begin{pmatrix}
  \texttt{... ... ... MRXV} \\
  \texttt{... ... ... LMSI}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \texttt{... ... ... MRXV} \\
  \texttt{... ... ... SILM}
\end{pmatrix}
are potentially parts of certain solutions. If I will keep the cycles in the order as they were, there are $7 \cdot 7 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 441$ cases to test. The next step is to swap the 1st/2nd cycles and/or the 3rd/4th cycles. I am guessing that many cases will be rejected because they fail to make $\nu$ a 26-cycle. For examples, we can reject cases like,
\begin{pmatrix}
  \texttt{... ... ..L.. ..R..} \\
  \texttt{... ... ..R.. ..L..}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  \texttt{..C.. ... J..P ...} \\
  \texttt{..J.. ... P..C ...}
\end{pmatrix}
because $\texttt{(RL)}$ or $\texttt{(JPC)}$ makes that $\nu$ fails to become a 26-cycle. There are still lots of cases to test.
My first question. Is there a faster way without trying all cases?
Now using $\nu, \rho$, one solution is,
\begin{align}
N &=
\begin{pmatrix}
\texttt{AJPCZWRLFBDKOTYUQGENHXMIVS} \\
\texttt{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
\end{pmatrix}  \\
& = \texttt{(FIXVYOMW)(CDKLHUP)(ESZ)(BJ)(GR)(NT)(A)(Q)}
\end{align}
My second question. If I will rotate the the first row, it makes 26 possible solutions altogether, doesn't it? Update on 8 July 2024. Thanks to @Lieven. Now I know the answer is yes.
Update on 10 July 2024. Among 441 possible $\nu$, 28 of them are in the form of 26-cycle. They are,
\begin{align}
\nu = \ 
&\texttt{(ABYDVMSOGJCHEZNUXLRIWPFTKQ)}  \\
&\texttt{(ABYDVSOGJPCHEZNUXMIWRLFTKQ)}  \\
&\texttt{(AEDZUOBWPFJCYVMSGXLRIHQTNK)}  \\
&\texttt{(AEDZUOBWRLFJPCYVSGXMIHQTNK)}  \\
&\texttt{(AEUOBVMSGXLRIZHQTWPFJCDNYK)}  \\
&\texttt{(AEUOBVSGXMIZHQTWRLFJPCDNYK)}  \\
&\texttt{(AEZNUOBYDVMSGXLRIWPFJCHQTK)}  \\
&\texttt{(AEZNUOBYDVSGXMIWRLFJPCHQTK)}  \\
&\texttt{(AJCKOTZDHXLRIUQGEYWPFBNVMS)}  \\
&\texttt{(AJCZWPFBDKOTYUQGENHXLRIVMS)}  \\
&\texttt{(AJPCKOTZDHXMIUQGEYWRLFBNVS)}  \\
&\texttt{(AJPCZWRLFBDKOTYUQGENHXMIVS)}  \\
&\texttt{(AOXLRIWPFQEZNUTKBYDVMSJCHG)}  \\
&\texttt{(AOXMIWRLFQEZNUTKBYDVSJPCHG)}  \\
&\texttt{(AQJCNZVMSBUGOEWPFXLRIKTDYH)}  \\
&\texttt{(AQJCVMSBZYNWPFXLRIDUGOEKTH)}  \\
&\texttt{(AQJCZWPFXLRIVMSBDKTYUGOENH)}  \\
&\texttt{(AQJPCNZVSBUGOEWRLFXMIKTDYH)}  \\
&\texttt{(AQJPCVSBZYNWRLFXMIDUGOEKTH)}  \\
&\texttt{(AQJPCZWRLFXMIVSBDKTYUGOENH)}  \\
&\texttt{(ATYUENHJCZWPFGBDKXLRIVMSQO)}  \\
&\texttt{(ATYUENHJPCZWRLFGBDKXMIVSQO)}  \\
&\texttt{(ATZDHJCKXLRIUEYWPFGBNVMSQO)}  \\
&\texttt{(ATZDHJPCKXMIUEYWRLFGBNVSQO)}  \\
&\texttt{(AXLRIHOJCYVMSTNKGQBWPFEDZU)}  \\
&\texttt{(AXLRIZHOJCDNYKGQBVMSTWPFEU)}  \\
&\texttt{(AXMIHOJPCYVSTNKGQBWRLFEDZU)}  \\
&\texttt{(AXMIZHOJPCDNYKGQBVSTWRLFEU)}
.
\end{align}
Suppose $C = \texttt{(DYEJTGMNP)(HUWOXSQRK)(AVFI)(BZCL)}$ and,
\begin{align}
B &= \nu^{-1} A \nu  \\
C &= \nu^{-1} B \nu  \\
\nu &= N \rho N^{-1}  .  \\
\end{align}
Rejewski (1984, p.283) reported rather concisely that "writing $B$ beneath $A$, and $C$ beneath $B$, in every possible way is rather tedious. However, there are various tricks and technical means that make this subscription unnecessary, but whose description and, especially, justification would take us too far afield." My first question rephrased. Various tricks and technical means are what I am looking for.
Marian Rejewski (1984) The Mathematical Solution of the Enigma Cipher. In Wladyslaw Kozaczuk (1979). Christopher Kasparek, ed. tr. (1984) Enigma: How the German Cipher Was Broken and How It Was Read by the Allies in World War Two. Appendix E, pp.272-291. University Publications of America. ISBN 0-89093-547-5.

Try this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382239/how-to-solve-conjugation-equations-in-group-theory

First question: the condition is equivalent to $B=\nu^{-1}A\nu$ and that is satisfied by any permutation that maps the tuple to $(J, W, L, P)$ to one of $(M, R, X, V),$ $(R, X, V, M),$ $(X, V, M, R)$ or $(V, M, R, X).$
Second question: this is different from the first question mainly because $\rho$ and $\nu$ may have different cycle structures. It is solvable iff $\nu$ happens to consist of a single cycle of length $26$ just like $\rho$ does. If it does, write $\nu$ and $\rho$ as cycles, say $\nu=(A\ l_2\ l_3\ldots l_{26})$ and $\rho=(A\ B\ldots Z).$ Then one solution for $N$ is given in two-row notation by superimposing these two cycles:
$$N=\begin{pmatrix}
A & B & \ldots & Z\\
A & l_2 & \ldots & l_{26}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
It can be verified directly that this $N$ satisfies the equation by computing the result of $N\rho N^{-1}$ applied on $l_i:$
$N\rho N^{-1}(l_i)=N\rho(\hbox{$i$-th letter of $A-Z$)}=N(\hbox{$(i+1)$-th letter of $A-Z$})=l_{i+1}=\nu(l_i).$
The permutation $N$ need not consist of a single cycle of length $26.$
If $N$ is a solution then so is $N\rho^k$ for any integer $k$ (but these represent only $26$ different solutions because $\rho$ is a cycle of length $26$).

Thanks. Yes, both $\rho, \nu$ are in the form of 26-cycle. And $N$ is in the form of 9, 9, 4, 4-cycles. I guess I'll need a writing pad and some pens.

Okay, I get it. Since $A, B$ are in the form of 9, 9, 4, 4-cycles. There are $9 \cdot 4 = 36 $ solutions to $\nu$. I know for a fact that $N$ is in the form for 8, 7, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1-cycles. I'll need to get on with it. Many thanks.

I think you've got $N$ backwards (or we may be using a different convention to write cycles).

I have followed the convention Rejewski (1980) used. One way or the other, I don't think there are any practical differences. https://eudml.org/doc/264403

I'm not sure what you mean by "any permutation that maps the tuple $(J,W,L,P)$ to $(M,R,X,V)$." However, for $ \nu\ $  to satisfy the equation  $\ \nu^{−1}A\nu=B\ $  it's not sufficient for it merely to map the set $\ {{\tt J,W,L,P}}\ $  to the set $\ {{\tt M,R,X,V}}\ .$ If $\ \nu(\mathfrak{x})=\mathfrak{y}\ ,$ where  $\ \mathfrak{x}\in{{\tt J,W,L,P}}\ $ and $\ \mathfrak{y}\in{{\tt M,R,X,V}}\ ,$ and $\ \nu^{−1}A\nu=B\ ,$ then $\ \nu\big(B^i(\mathfrak{x}))=A^i(\mathfrak{y})\ $ for all $\ i\ .$

Thus, $\ \nu_{/{{\tt J,W,L,P}}}\ $ must be one of the four mappings
$$\pmatrix{{\tt JWLP\MRXV}},\ \pmatrix{{\tt JWLP\RXVM}},\ \pmatrix{{\tt JWLP\XVMR}},\ \text{or}\ \ \pmatrix{{\tt JWLP\VMRX}}\ .$$

I meant only the first of those four, but you are right that there are three other possibilities. I am going to modify my answer in that sense.

I know there are exactly four possible $A$, they are
$\mathtt{(JM)(LX)(PR)(VW)}$,
$\mathtt{(JR)(LV)(MW)(PX)}$,
$\mathtt{(JX)(LM)(PV)(RW)}$ or
$\mathtt{(JV)(LR)(MP)(WX)}$ .
However, I made a terrible mistake in the way I asked my question. I thought I could decouple the 9, 9-cycles from the 4, 4-cycles. I could not. I accidentally, turn $A$ into a 18, 4, 4-cycle. I'll make a change.

I am sorry @ Lieven @lonzaleggiera. I think my question was so ill defined. I ought to delete it in a few days. I apologise for wasting your time. Your answers are very useful to me. Without them, I wouldn't realise I was so wrong.

It looks like that I can't delete a question with an answer. I have re-worded my question entirely.

@Lieven "If $N$ is a solution then so is $Nρ^k$  for any integer k." Got it. Many thanks.

I am getting the hang of it. Suppose $A=\alpha_1\alpha_2\beta_1\beta_2, B=\alpha_3\alpha_4\beta_3\beta_4,C=\alpha_5\alpha_6\beta_5\beta_6$ as the order listed in the question. Aligning $\alpha_3$ to $\alpha_1$ and using $\beta_3, \beta_4, \beta_5, \beta_6$, we eliminate 8 of 9 possible matches leaving only $\mathtt{(AJ)}$ could be a part of $\nu$. Similarly, aligning $\alpha_4$ to $\alpha_1$, only $\mathtt{(AY)}$ could be a part of $\nu$. And hence there are only $(1\cdot1+1\cdot 0) \cdot (3\cdot3+3\cdot4)=21$ possible $\nu$ to test instead of $441+588+324+432=1785$. Quite achievable by hand.

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
If the permutation $\ A\ $ is a product,
$$
A=A_1A_2\dots A_r\ ,
$$
of disjoint cycles $\ A_1,A_2,\dots,A_r\ ,$ then
$$
\nu^{-1}A\nu=\big(\nu^{-1}A_1\nu\big)\big(\nu^{-1}A_2\nu\big)\dots\big(\nu^{-1}A_r\nu\big)\ ,
$$
and if $\ A_i=\pmatrix{a_{i0}\,a_{i1}\,\dots\,a_{i\,(\ell_i-1)}}\ ,$ then
$$
\nu^{-1}A_i\nu=\pmatrix{c_{i0}\,c_{i1}\,\dots\,c_{i\,(\ell_i-1)}}\ ,
$$
where $\ c_{ij}=a_{ij}^\nu\ .$ Thus, $\ \nu^{-1}A_i\nu\ $ is  a cycle with the same length $\ \ell_i\ $ as $\ A_i\ .$ Also, since $\ \big\{a_{i0},a_{i1},\dots,a_{i\,(\ell_i-1)}\big\}\cap$$\,\big\{a_{j0},a_{j1},\dots,$$\,a_{j\,(\ell_j-1)}\big\}=\varnothing\ $ for $\ i\ne j\ ,$ because $\ A_i,A_j\ $ are disjoint, then
\begin{align}
\big\{c_{i1},c_{i2},\dots,c_{i\,(\ell_i-1)}\big\}&\cap\big\{c_{j0},c_{j1},\dots,c_{j\,(\ell_j-1)}\big\}\\
&=\big(\big\{a_{i0},a_{i1},\dots,a_{i\,(\ell_i-1)}\big\}\cap\big\{a_{j0},a_{j1},\dots,a_{j\,(\ell_j-1)}\big\}\big)^\nu\\
&=\varnothing\ ,
\end{align}
and so $\ \nu^{-1}A_i\nu\ $ and $\ \nu^{-1}A_j\nu\ $ are also disjoint.  It follows from this that $\ \nu^{-1}A\nu\ $ must always have the same cycle structure as $\ A\ .$ Therefore a necessary condition for the equation $\ B=\nu^{-1}A\nu\ $ to  have a solution for $\ \nu\ $ is that $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ have the same cycle structure. This condition is also sufficient.  If $\ B\ $ is a product
$$
B=B_1B_2\dots B_r
$$
of disjoint cycles $\ B_1,B_2,\dots,B_r\ ,$ and $\ B=\nu^{-1}A\nu\ ,$ then $\ B_i\ $ could be any of the cycles $\ \nu^{-1}A_j\nu\ $ for which $\ A_j\ $ has the same length as $\ B_i\ .$ If $\ B_i\ed\pmatrix{b_{i0}\,b_{i1}\,\dots\,b_{i\,(\ell_j-1)}}\ ,$ then
\begin{align}
\hspace{-2em}\pmatrix{b_{i0}\,b_{i1}\,\dots\,b_{i\,(\ell_j-1)}}&=\nu^{-1}A_j\nu\\
&=\pmatrix{a_{j0}^\nu\,a_{j1}^\nu\,\dots\,a_{j\,(\ell_j-1)}^\nu}\ ,\tag{1}\label{e1}
\end{align}
and $\ a_{j0}^\nu=b_{ik}\ $ for some $\ k\in\big\{0,1,\dots,\ell_j-1\big\}\ .$ For $\ s=0,1,\dots,\ell_j-1\ $ we then have
\begin{align}
a_{js}^\nu&=a_{j0}^{A_j^s\nu}\\
&=a_{j0}^{\nu B_i^s}\\
&=b_{ik}^{B_i^s}\\
&=b_{i\,(k+s)\pmod{\ell_j}}\\
&=b_{is}^{B_i^k}\\
&=a_{js}^{\nu_0B_i^k}\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ \nu_0:\big\{a_{j0},a_{j1},\dots,a_{j\,(\ell_j-1)}\big\}\rightarrow\big\{b_{i0},b_{i1},\dots,b_{i\,(\ell_j-1)}\big\}\ $ is the mapping defined by the table
$$
\nu_0\ed\pmatrix{a_{j0}&a_{j1}&\dots&a_{j\,(\ell_j-1)}\\
b_{i0}&b_{i1}&\dots&b_{i\,(\ell_j-1)}}\ .
$$
In other words, $\ \nu_{/\{a_{j0},a_{j1},\dots,a_{j\,(\ell_j-1)}\}}=\nu_0B_i^k\ .$ Conversely, if $\ \nu\ $ is any permutation satisfying this last condition for some $\ k\in\big\{0,1,\dots,$$\,\ell_j-1\big\}\ ,$  then it will also satisfy the equation $\ \nu^{-1}A_j\nu=B_i\ .$
If $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ both have the same cycle structure $\ r_1\times\ell_1+r_2\times\ell_2+$$\,\dots+$$\,r_\kappa\times\ell_\kappa\ ,$ where, for each $\ i\ ,$$\ r_i\ $ is the number of cycles of length $\ \ell_i\  ,$ and $\ \ell_1>\ell_2>\dots>\ell_\kappa\ ,$ then $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ can always be written as products
\begin{align}
A&=\prod_{i=1}^\kappa\prod_{j=1}^{r_i}A_{ij}\ \ \text{and}\\
B&=\prod_{i=1}^\kappa\prod_{j=1}^{r_i}B_{ij}\
\end{align}
with $\ A_{ij}\ $ disjoint cycles, and $\ B_{ij}\ $ disjoint cycles, such that, for each $\ i\ ,$ $\ A_{i1},B_{i1},A_{i2},B_{i2}, \dots,A_{ir_i},B_{ir_i}\ $ have length $\ \ell_i\ .$ If $\ B=\nu^{-1}A\nu\ ,$ then $\ B_{ij}\ $ could be any of the cycles $\ \nu^{-1}A_{i1}\nu, \nu^{-1}A_{i2}\nu,\dots,\nu^{-1}A_{ir_i}\nu\ ,$ and must be one of them.  If
\begin{align}
A_{ij}&=\pmatrix{a_{ij0}&a_{ij1}&\dots&a_{ij\,(\ell_i-1)}}\ \ \text{and}\\
B_{ij}&=\pmatrix{\,b_{ij0}&\,b_{ij1}&\dots&b_{ij\,(\ell_i-1)}}\ ,
\end{align}
then it follows from the above discussion that
$$
\nu=\nu_{\pi_1\pi_2\dots\pi_\kappa}\prod_{i=1}^\kappa B_{i1}^{k_{i1}}B_{i2}^{k_{i2}}\dots B_{ir_i}^{k_{ir_i}}\tag{2}\label{e2}
$$
where $\ 0\le k_1,k_2,\dots,k_{r_i}\le\ell_i-1\ ,$ for each $\ i\ $$\ \pi_i\ $ is a permutation on the integers $\ 1,2,\dots,r_i\ ,$ and $\ \nu_{\pi_1\pi_2\dots\pi_\kappa}\ $ is the permutation defined on each of the sets $\ \bigcup_\limits{j=1}^{r_i}\big\{a_{ij0},a_{ij1},\dots,a_{ij\,(\ell_i-1)}\big\}\ $ by the tables
\begin{align}
&\nu_{\pi_1\pi_2\dots\pi_\kappa/\bigcup_\limits{j=1}^{r_i}\{b_{ij0},b_{ij1},\dots,b_{ij\,(\ell_i-1)}\}}\ed\\
&\pmatrix{a_{i10}&a_{i11}&\dots&a_{i1\,(\ell_i-1)}&a_{i20}&\dots&a_{ijk}&\dots&a_{ir_i\,(\ell_i-1)}\\
b_{i1^\pi0}&b_{i1^\pi1}&\dots&b_{i1^\pi\,(\ell_i-1)}&b_{i2^\pi0}&\dots&b_{ij^\pi k}&\dots&b_{i r_i^\pi\,(\ell_i-1)}}\ .
\end{align}
The total number of distinct sets of values for $\ k_1,k_2,\dots,k_{r_i}\ $ and $\ \nu_{\pi_1\pi_2\dots\pi_\kappa}\ $ on the right side of equation \eqref{e2} is
$$
\prod_{i=1}^\kappa\big(r_i!\ell_i^{r_i}\big)\ ,
$$
and each of these, in combination with the definition of $\ \nu_{\pi_1\pi_2\dots\pi_\kappa}\ ,$ will give a solution
to the equation $\ B=\nu^{-1}A\nu\ $ for $\ \nu\ $ when $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ both have that cycle structure.  Not all these solutions are necessarily distinct, however, so the total number of distinct solutions could well be less than $\ \prod_\limits{i=1}^\kappa\big(r_i!\ell_i^{r_i}\big)\ .$
For your problem, with
\begin{align}
A &= \texttt{ (AFOQSKUHG)(BETCDNIYZ)(JWLP)(MRXV) } \\
B &= \texttt{ (AOQXEJBTG)(DNYZKHVUW)(CPRF)(ILMS) }\ , 
\end{align}
you have $\ \kappa=2,r_1=r_2=2,\ell_1=9\ $ and $\ \ell_2=4\ ,$ so there could be as many as up to $\ \big(2!9^2\big)\big(2!4^2\big)=5184\ $ solutions for $\ \nu\ $ of the equation $\ B=\nu^{-1}A\nu\ ,$ given by
\begin{align}
\nu&=\nu_{i_1i_2}{\tt  (AOQXEJBTG)}^{k_{11}}{\tt (DNYZKHVUW)}^{k_{12}}{\tt (CPRF)}^{k_{21}}{\tt (ILMS)}^{k_{22}}\ ,\tag{3}\label{e3}
\end{align}
where $\ 0\le k_{11},k_{12}\le8,0\le k_{21},k_{22}\le4, 1\le i_1,i_2\le2\ ,$ and $\ \nu_{i_1i_2}\ $ are the permutations given by
\begin{align}
\nu_{11}&\ed\pmatrix{{\tt AFOQSKUHGBETCDNIYZJWLPMRXV}\\
  { \color{red} {\tt AOQXEJBTG} } { \color{blue} {\tt DNYZKHVUW} } { \color{green} {\tt CPRF} }  { \color{orange} {\tt ILMS} }}\\
&={\tt (FOQXMIVSENHTYUBDKJCZWP)(LR)}\\
\nu_{12}&\ed\pmatrix{{\tt AFOQSKUHGBETCDNIYZJWLPMRXV}\\
 {  \color{red} {\tt AOQXEJBTG} } { \color{blue} {\tt DNYZKHVUW} }   { \color{orange} {\tt ILMS} } { \color{green} {\tt CPRF} }}\\
&={\tt (FOQXRPSENHTYUBDKJIV)(ZWLMC)}\\
\nu_{21}&\ed\pmatrix{{\tt AFOQSKUHGBETCDNIYZJWLPMRXV}\\
  { \color{blue} {\tt DNYZKHVUW}} {  \color{red} {\tt AOQXEJBTG} } { \color{green} {\tt CPRF} }  { \color{orange} {\tt ILMS} }}\\
&={\tt (ADEOYTQZGWPFNJCXMIB)(SKHUV)(LR)}\\
\nu_{22}&\ed\pmatrix{{\tt AFOQSKUHGBETCDNIYZJWLPMRXV}\\
  { \color{blue} {\tt DNYZKHVUW}} {  \color{red} {\tt AOQXEJBTG} } {  \color{orange} {\tt ILMS}}  { \color{green} {\tt CPRF} }}\\
&={\tt (ADEOYTQZGWLMCXRPSKHUVFNJIB)}\ .
\end{align}
As you're already aware, not all solutions $\ \nu\ $ of $\ \nu^{-1}A\nu=B\ $ will allow the equation $\ N\rho N^{-1}=\nu\ $ to be solved for $\ N\ .$ This will be possible if and only if $\ \nu\ $ is a single cycle of length $26$.  We can therefore immediately rule out those values of $\ \nu\ $ given by equation \eqref{e3} with $\ i_1=i_2=1,$$\, k_{11}\in\{0,8\},$$\,k_{12}=5,k_{21}=2\ $ or $\ k_{22}=2\ ,$ with $\ i_1=1, i_2=2,$$\, k_{11}\in\{0,8\},$$\,k_{12}=5,$$\,k_{21}=1\ $ or $\ k_{22}=3\ ,$  with $\ i_1=2,i_2=1,$$\, k_{11}\in\{2,8\},$$\,k_{12}\in\{3,5\},$$\,k_{21}=2\ $ or $\ k_{22}=2\ ,$ or with $\ i_1=2, i_2=1,$$\, k_{11}\in\{2,8\},k_{12}\in\{3,5\},$$\,k_{21}=1\ $ or $\ k_{22}=3\ ,$ because all those permutations are easily seen to have fixed points. This leaves $56\times9=504$ potential solutions of the form given by equation \eqref{e3} with each of $\ i_1=i_2=1\ $ and $\ i_1=1,i_2=2\ ,$ and $49\times9=441$ such potential solutions with each of $\ i_1=2,$$\,i_2=1\ $ and $\ i_1=i_2=2\ ,$ for a total of $\ 2\times(504+441)=$$\,1890\ $ potential solutions remaining.
I wrote a Magma script to enumerate all the potential solutions generated by equation \eqref{e3} and eliminate all those that weren't single cycles of length $26$.  For $\ i_1=i_2=1\ $ this just gave the same $28$ solutions you've already found.  However there are  also $36$ solutions for $\ i_1=1,i_2=2\ ,$ $20$
for $\ i_1=2,i_2=1\ ,$ and $38$ for $\ i_1=i_2=2\ .$ Here they are.
For $\ i_1=1, i_2=2$:
\begin{align}
{\tt (AXCYVPIHOJLSTNKGQBWMRFEDZU)\\
(AQJLSBZYNWMCVFXRPIDUGOEKTH)\\
(AEUOBVPIZHQTWMRFJLSGXCDNYK)\\(AQJLSBUGOEWMCNZVFXRPIKTDYH)\\
(AXCHOJLSTKGQBYDVPIWMRFEZNU)\\
(ABYDVRCHEZNUXPLIWSOGJMFTKQ)\\
(ATYUENHJMFGBDKXPLIVRCZWSQO)\\
(AOXPLIWSJMFQEZNUTKBYDVRCHG)\\
(AOXPSJIWLMFQEZNUTKBYDVRCHG)\\
(AQJMFXPLIVRCZWSBDKTYUGOENH)\\
(ATZDHJMFGBNVRCKXPLIUEYWSQO)\\
(AXRPIZHOJLSTWMCDNYKGQBVFEU)\\
(AXRPIWMCHOJLSTKGQBYDVFEZNU)\\
(AXPSTKGQBYDVRCHOJIWLMFEZNU)\\
(AEUOBVFJLSGXRPIZHQTWMCDNYK)\\
(AEZNUOBYDVFJLSGXRPIWMCHQTK)\\
(AEDZUOBWMCYVFJLSGXRPIHQTNK)\\ (AQJLSBUGOEWMRFXCNZVPIKTDYH)\\
(AQJLSBNVFXRPIUGOEYWMCKTZDH)\\
(AJIVRCZWLMFBDKOTYUQGENHXPS)\\
(AJIUQGEYWLMFBNVRCKOTZDHXPS)\\
(ATZDHJIUEYWLMFGBNVRCKXPSQO)\\
(AQJLSBZYNWMRFXCVPIDUGOEKTH)\\
(AEDZUOBWMRFJLSGXCYVPIHQTNK)\\
(AQJMFXPLIUGOEYWSBNVRCKTZDH)\\
(AJMFBDKOTYUQGENHXPLIVRCZWS)\\
(AQJIUGOEYWLMFXPSBNVRCKTZDH)\\
(AJMFBNVRCKOTZDHXPLIUQGEYWS)\\
(AXPLIWSTKGQBYDVRCHOJMFEZNU)\\
(AQJIVRCZWLMFXPSBDKTYUGOENH)\\
(AXRPIHOJLSTNKGQBWMCYVFEDZU)\\
(ABYDVRCHEZNUXPSOGJIWLMFTKQ)\\
(AQJLSBNVPIUGOEYWMRFXCKTZDH)\\
 (AXCDNYKGQBVPIZHOJLSTWMRFEU)\\
(ATYUENHJIVRCZWLMFGBDKXPSQO)\\
(AEZNUOBYDVPIWMRFJLSGXCHQTK).}
\end{align}
For $\ i_1=2, i_2=1$:
\begin{align}
{\tt (AHZGKNJFVMSDEOUYTQWCXLPRIB)\\
(AKDJPCEQUNBOVITXSWRMLFHYGZ)\\
(AZGYTQVMSUDEOHNJFKWCXLPRIB)\\
(ADEOYTQZGWRMLFNJPCXSKHUVIB)\\
(AYTQHDEOKUWRMLFZGNJPCXSVIB)\\
(AHZGKNJPCXSDEOUYTQWRMLFVIB)\\
(AZGYTQVMSUDEOHNJPCXLFKWRIB)\\
(AKDXSWRMLFHYBGZTOVIJPCQUNE)\\
(AKDJPCEQUNBOVMSWRITXLFHYGZ)\\
(AKDBQUNTEXLPRIGZOVMSWCJFHY)\\
(AKDQUNXLFHYJPCOVMSWRIEGZBT)\\
(AVMSNJFUZGHKYTQDEOWCXLPRIB)\\
(AHZGKNJPCXLFVMSDEOUYTQWRIB)\\
(AKDGZXLPRIOVMSWCTBEJFHYQUN)\\
(AHZXLPRIOUYQWCTBEJFVMSDGKN)\\
(AKDQUNXSWRMLFHYJPCOVIEGZBT)\\
(AKDXLPRIJFHYBGZTOVMSWCQUNE)\\
(AVMSNJPCXLFUZGHKYTQDEOWRIB)\\
(AKDXLFHYBGZTOVMSWRIJPCQUNE)\\
(ADXSKHUVIJPCQZTOYBGWRMLFNE).}
\end{align}
For $\ i_1=i_2=2$:
\begin{align}
{\tt (AHZXPIOUYQWMFVRCTBEJLSDGKN)\\
(AYTQHDEOKUWLMCXRPSVFZGNJIB)\\
(AHZGKNJLSDEOUYTQWMFVRCXPIB)\\
(AKDGZXCTBEJIOVPSWLMRFHYQUN)\\
(ADXCQZTOYBGWSKHUVPLIJMRFNE)\\
(AHZXCTBEJIOUYQWLMRFVPSDGKN)\\
(AKDGZXRPSWLMCTBEJIOVFHYQUN)\\
(AYTQHDEOKUWMFZGNJLSVRCXPIB)\\
(ADEOYTQZGWLMCXRPSKHUVFNJIB)\\
(AKDJITXCEQUNBOVPSWLMRFHYGZ)\\
(AHZXCTBEJMRFVPLIOUYQWSDGKN)\\
(AKDBQUNTEXRPSWLMCJIGZOVFHY)\\
(AYGNBOKUWLMCEQHDJITXRPSVFZ)\\
(ADJITXRPSKHUVFNBOYGWLMCEQZ)\\
(ADXRPLIJMCQZTOYBGWSKHUVFNE)\\
(AKDXPIJLSWMFHYBGZTOVRCQUNE)\\
(ADEOYTQZGWSKHUVFNJMCXRPLIB)\\
(AZXRPSUDGYQVFKWLMCTBEJIOHN)\\
(AZXCTBEJMRFKWSUDGYQVPLIOHN)\\
(AKDJITXRPSWLMCEQUNBOVFHYGZ)\\
(AYTQHDEOKUWSVFZGNJMCXRPLIB)\\ (AVFUZGHKYTQDEOWSNJMCXRPLIB)\\
(AZOHNTEXCJMRFKWSUDBQVPLIGY)\\
(AKDQUNXRPSWLMCOVFHYJIEGZBT)\\
(AKDGZXPIOVRCTBEJLSWMFHYQUN)\\
(ADJMRFNBOYGWSKHUVPLITXCEQZ)\\
(AZGYTQVFKWSUDEOHNJMCXRPLIB)\\
(AKDQUNXCOVPSWLMRFHYJIEGZBT)\\
(ADGWLMCTBEJIOYQZXRPSKHUVFN)\\
(AZGYTQVFKWLMCXRPSUDEOHNJIB)\\
(AYGNBOKUWSVPLITXCEQHDJMRFZ)\\
(AZOHNTEXRPSUDBQVFKWLMCJIGY)\\
(AKDBQUNTEXCJIGZOVPSWLMRFHY)\\
(AVFUZGHKYTQDEOWLMCXRPSNJIB)\\
(ADXPIJLSKHUVRCQZTOYBGWMFNE)\\
(ADGWSKHUVPLIOYQZXCTBEJMRFN)\\
(AKDBQUNTEXPIGZOVRCJLSWMFHY)\\
(ADEOYTQZGWMFNJLSKHUVRCXPIB). }
\end{align}

Thanks for such a detailed exploration. I can concur that I got 28, 36, 20 and 38 suitable solutions for $\nu$ too.
